# SwiftUI Group of Text + Link -> compiler error

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, swiftui

I'm trying to create a group with some Text + bold text + Links, but I get an error and I'm not sure why ir wouldn't compile. Not sure if Links and Texts can't be together. Anyone has any suggestions on how to make this work?

The error is:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

[image: code]

Comment: Too much text views. Split them up if possible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine Text and Link elements with +.

[image]

**Solution 1:**

```
if let tcUrl = URL(string: "www.tc.com"), let policyUrl = URL(string: "www.policy.com") {
            Group {
                    Text("Byselecting ") + Text("Agree and sign up ").bold() + Text("below, I agree to the ")
                    Link(destination: tcUrl, label: {
                        Text("Terms & Conditions")
                    })
                    Text("and") + Text("")
                    Link(destination: policyUrl, label: {
                        Text("Privacy Policy")
                    })
            }
        }
```

**Solution 2:**

[image]

```
if let tcUrl = URL(string: "www.tc.com"), let policyUrl = URL(string: "www.policy.com") {
            Group {
                    Text("Byselecting ") + Text("Agree and sign up ").bold() + Text("below, I agree to the ")
                HStack {
                    Link(destination: tcUrl, label: {
                            Text("Terms & Conditions")
                    })
                    Text("and")
                    Link(destination: policyUrl, label: {
                        Text("Privacy Policy")
                    })
                }
                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @ufuk-köşker! Yeah, I tried that too, but I can't get that to look like a label. Even setting the alignment it breaks the lines from group to HStack =[

Comment: I did not understand how you want to do something. My English is not good. It would be better if you draw this in a design application and submit it.